# Searching and listing folders using as source a Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, nas

As a junior system admin I was tasked with a data management chore on our NAS device.

By using an Excel workbook as the source (the cells of a specific column of this workbook), I have to use Windows File Manager to search our NAS location for the folders that they have the exact same name as the cells of that Excel column.

Is a way to search a disk location by using names in Excel cells to match the folders with these names from the cells columns?

I attach a image from the column and the cells so you can have a better idea.

[image: excel column]

Comment: Yes this is fairly easily done in powershell. A great tool to learn for system admins. Powershell can enumerate excel / csv Files and you can write some logic to enumerate the files and folders on the drive and see if it matches up with your list.

Comment: Could you give me some leads please about some specifics functions /commands about that? Google till now hasnt provided something specific since i want powershell to list me the paths where are the folders since i dont know their exact path. I'd prefer though a more visual way since i have to copy these folders to another place after i find them...

Comment: You'd probably need to look at `Get-ChildItem` and maybe `Where-Object`. One could give you a "tree" (not to be confused with the cmd `tree`) and should be able to filter it for you. If it's not able to filter sufficiently look at `Where-Object`. Something along the lines of `gci -Recurse | where Name -like '*1999*'` could be the result.

Comment: It’s not a single command. It’s a series of concepts. How to read excel files; how to traverse directory tree recursively; how to check if string contains a substring in an array; how to copy a folder.  You might also check agent ransack or file locator pro. They can do Boolean logic searches.

Comment: thank you very much for your precious information guys!!! Yes i thought about Get-Childitem function as well since i had use it in another job where i was looking just for files bigger than 300mb on the NAS. So i thought this time i should use it for just matching names from a excel. But i was thinking as well if there is a function or VBA on MS excel where it can be linked directly with file manager of windows and search from a column or a selected number of cells

Answer (score 0):

As other suggested a bit of scripting in Powershell will make this happen.  If not for this project, then the next one.  I consider `import-csv` to be the strongest argument for an admin learning to script. Here's an example that might help you get started

```
# csvtest.ps1
# assume this file name
$fname = "c:\data\naslist.csv"
$fcontent = import-csv $fname
# assume these column names in the csv: name and size
foreach ($row in $fcontent) {

    write-host $row.name $row.size 
}
```